# Is it possible to use the AWS CLI to wait until an instance is 'online' and finished with setup/configuration steps of opsworks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks, aws-cli, amazon-ec2

I create a new instance for my opsworks stack and want to wait for it to be fully booted up in the 'online' status, and i thought that

```
aws ec2 wait instance-running
```

would do just that but it seems it only waits for the instance to be started, not completely finished with setup/configuration.

Is it possible to wait for it to be fully booted with the AWS CLI with something I may have overlooked? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no actual AWS CLI command for OpsWorks that allows this action. This does not leave you out of luck though, You can run the describe command on repeat until the status is in the online State. only issue you might have with this method is running API limits, so you should include a sleep function to limit the number of calls.

This is close to what you could use, I have not had time to test it exactly.

```
while [$STATUS != 'Status:Online'; do
    STATUS=`aws opsworks --region us-east-1 describe-instances --instance-id 8c2673b9-3fe5-420d-9cfa-78d875ee7687 | grep "Status" | sed 's/\"//g'`
    sleep -m 1
done
```

For your future reference:

Here are all of the AWS OpsWorks CLI commands:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/index.html

Here is the specific command I was talking about:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/describe-instances.html

Let me know If I can provide some clarification!

Comment: Thank you! This should work well enough for me for now!